# Does the multisample texture need to be mipmapped if the main texture is mipmapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

With metal, does the multisample texture need to be mipmapped if the main texture is mipmapped? I read the apple doc, but didn't get any information about it.

Comment: What do you mean **"main texture is mipmapped"**?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I mean that i create the texture with mipmapped = true (ie: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/textures/improving_filtering_quality_and_sampling_performance/creating_a_mipmapped_texture?language=objc)

Answer (score 4):

***Mipmapping*** is for a texture from which you will take samples, typically a texture that is covering one of the models in your scene. Mipmapping is a mechanism for smoothing out sampling at varying levels of detail as an object moves closer or further from the camera (and so appears larger and more detailed, or smaller and less detailed).

***Multisampling*** is for the texture that you will render ***to*** in a scene. This generally means the texture that is displayed on screen. Multisampling allows you to render to a texture that is larger than the screen, and then *resolve* that texture down to the screen resolution, in order to reduce aliasing (jagged lines).

So...in almost all cases, mipmapping and multi-sampling are mutually exclusive. Mipmaps are for a texture that is used as a source, and multisampling is for a texture that is used as a destination.

Some textures might be used as both a source ***and*** destination. These are textures that you render to dynamically (destination), say to create pattern,, and then sample from to cover a model in your scene (source).

So at first look it might seem conceivable that you might dynamically render to a texture using multisampling, ***and*** then want to sample from that texture using mipmapping. However, in this case, there is no point in making this texture multisampled. You would simply render to a larger texture, mipmap it, and sample from it. Multisampling this texture would take an additional *resolve* effort, and would not add anything.